# DLT logging file parsing

Tags: c++, logparser, dlt-daemon

After reading the DLT Log, I want to parse it and store it in the field I want.
It is never a DLT VIEWER implementation. I simply want to read the log and then just save the log in my structure.

Outputting to the DLT LOG has already been implemented.

Currently I have implemented the following code to read the DLT Log.

```
FILE *pLogFile = NULL;
pLogFile = fopen(DLTfilename, "rb") ;
if ( pLogFile )
{
    while ( fgets( buff, gBuffSize, pLogFile ) )
    {
        for ( int i=0; i < gBuffSize - 13 ; ++i )
        {
            // LF
            if ( buff[i] ==  0x0A )
            {
                break ;
            }
        //...............
        //read and save
        //...............
        }
    }
}
```

The above code scan each byte until it finds the desired string, but it is so slow! I'm looking for a way to optimize it.

I've tried several ways to read each line, but I could not read it as a separator like "`\n`", and when I read it with a program like notepad, I noticed that the characters were mixed.

I have two questions.

1. I want to know the format of DLT Log.

I searched the internet but I could not get any clue about its structure.

2. If you are a developer who has read the DLT Log, I would like to know how to improve the above code.

It's enough to let me know what sites I can refer to.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please consult the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on dos and donts when asking a question. That will help with your future inquires.

Comment: @Raw N There was a part I missed. Thanks for your advice. I will definitely check to the help page

Comment: I found this documentation for DLT log: https://at.projects.genivi.org/wiki/download/attachments/11567133/AUTOSAR_SWS_DiagnosticLogAndTrace.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1459989613000&api=v2

Comment: @KhouriGiordano Superb!! Thank you very much. I'll take a look.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano 
I'm sorry. I've read the article hard, but I do not seem to have anything to do with the above questions. Or I can not read it properly........

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Basic structure of a DLT log format: header + payload

Autosar std 20-11 terminology:

```
Log and trace message:
A log and trace message contains all data and options to describe a log
and trace event in a software. A log and trace message consists of a
header and payload.
```

Header:

```
+Pattern: DLT0x01
+Broken time (ISO C)
+Microsecond of broken time
+Epoch of system/Timestamp
+Msg counter
+ECU ID
+APP ID
+Info of msg type and length
+Verbose status
+Number of arguments
```

In header: Standard header + Extended header

##### For further information:

[DLt plugin (javascript), also doing the same parsing work (50% progress)](https://github.com/minminlittleshrimp/DLT-on-Web)

[DLT specification doc Autosar standard R20-11](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/standards/R20-11/CP/AUTOSAR_SWS_DiagnosticLogAndTrace.pdf)

[Message format (5.1) in R20-11 Autosar protocolv1](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/standards/R20-11/FO/AUTOSAR_PRS_LogAndTraceProtocol.pdf)

#### 2. For optimizing the code:

I suggest looking into some dlt_client implementations including their decoded mechanism (dlt-receive -a, dlt-viewer, dlt-convert -a, etc)